# Cutting edf file and save it in edf format using matlab

Tags: matlab, european-data-format

I have an edf file that contains data with 3000++ samples.

What I need is using only the first half of the data (1500++ samples).

How to cut the edf file and save it into an edf file again?

Comment: Might I humbly suggest you take a look at the [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) section?

Comment: i think im already make my question short, clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this File Exchange submission: [Reading and saving of data in the EDF+](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38641-reading-and-saving-of-data-in-the-edf+)

You can read the file, cut the data and save it again:

```
% Read the file    
[data, header] = readEDF(filename);

% Keep only the first half (data is in a cell array)
data = cellfun(@(x) (1:round(numel(x)/2)), data, 'UniformOutput', false);

% Update this header field
header.records = round(header.records/2);

% Save the file
SaveEDF(filename, data, header);
```